# Java try catch not handling IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I was having some problem when try to try catch the IndexOutOfBoundsException for a List in Java. So I declared my list with 2 elements as:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2"));
```

Then I tried to do a try catch:

```
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("(" + (i + 1) + ")" + list.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    try{
        option = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid option");
        sc.next();
        continue;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Option input mismatch.");
        sc.next();
        continue;
    } 
    sc.nextLine();
    if (option == 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        // scanner takes in input
    } else if (option == 2) {
        System.out.print("Enter desc: ");
        // scanner takes in input
    }
type = list.get((option - 1));
} while (option <= 0 || option >= 3);
```

However, when I entered anything larger than 2 for option, it threw me IndexOutOfBounds exception but I thought I did a try catch for it already?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `list` in the code you posted?

Comment: Why would `nextInt` throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?  Please include the code that did actually throw it.

Comment: If the exception is coming from your `list`, then the `try` block has to contain the code that is using your `list` in order to be able to catch the exception.

Comment: probably it comes from somewhere else, please show the stack trace

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have already updated the question

Comment: And still, the `try` block needs to contain the line that is causing the exception.

Comment: I was thinking is it because of the type = ... that line is causing the problem? I have added a try catch there, but then let's say user entered anything larger than 2, it does not prompt for input again.

Comment: Why are you instantiating the list that way? You could simplify that line List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item2");

Comment: @khelwood Hello any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I think that you are not using exceptions very well. You can prevent that IndexOutOfBounds with an if. And as @rgettman said above nextInt is not goint to throw that exception, you do not need to catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("(" + (i + 1) + ")" + list.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(" ");

        try {
            option = sc.nextInt();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            sc.next();
            continue;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Option input mismatch.");
            sc.next();
            continue;
        }
        sc.nextLine();
        if (option == 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            // scanner takes in input
        } else if (option == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter desc: ");
            // scanner takes in input
        }
        try {
            type = list.get((option - 1));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            option=3;
        }
    } while (option <= 0 || option >= 3);
```

I have added new try-catch at type = list.get((option - 1));
To force user re-input option, I will set option to 3 at the catch cause

Comment: Hello, that's what I thought but it does not prompt user to enter input again thou. As in in I entered larger than 2, the first for loop that part wont print out again and ask for input

Comment: What do you got in console?

Comment: just an empty space and I have to enter any value then the for loop that part will come out after that. Ah alright I knew already because of the sc.next() in last try catch and that 's  why

Comment: You need to put some promt into console, for example System.out.print("Re-enter the option: ");

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to catch the exception if you don't use an invalid value to call the list.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option;
    try {
        option = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(list.get(option));
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid option");
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Option input mismatch.");
    }

    sc.close();
```

Comment: I figured out that the problem came from this line: type = list.get((option - 1));. After I surround it with a try catch, the error is gone but the problem is, when user entered anything larger than 2, it does not prompt for input again

Answer (score 0):

You also can do it like this, it will loop till you enter a valid value and after a valid value is entered ask for name or whatever(not implemented)

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = 0;
    while(!(option == 1 || option==2) ) {

        try {
            option = sc.nextInt();              
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Option input mismatch.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list.get(option-1));
    sc.close();
```